# Pip install failing with error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1 on Big Sur 11.1

Tags: python, xcode, macos, pip, clang

I'm on MacOs Big Sur 11.1. I'm unable to use pip install. When trying to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get the following error:

```
copying pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas/test_construction.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas
copying pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas/test_partial_slicing.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas
copying pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas/test_ops.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas
copying pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas/test_arithmetic.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas
copying pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas/test_timedelta_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas
copying pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas/test_tools.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/tests/indexes/timedeltas
creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/tslibs
copying pandas/_libs/tslibs/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/tslibs
creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/api/types
copying pandas/api/types/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/api/types
creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/api/extensions
copying pandas/api/extensions/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/api/extensions
creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/io/formats/templates
copying pandas/io/formats/templates/html.tpl -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/io/formats/templates
UPDATING build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_version.py
set build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_version.py to '0.23.4'
running build_ext
building 'pandas._libs.algos' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas
creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c pandas/_libs/algos.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/algos.o -Wno-unused-function
In file included from pandas/_libs/algos.c:567:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822:
/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
 ^
1 warning generated.
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/algos.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -o build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/algos.cpython-37m-darwin.so
building 'pandas._libs.groupby' extension
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c pandas/_libs/groupby.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/groupby.o -Wno-unused-function
In file included from pandas/_libs/groupby.c:567:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822:
/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
 ^
pandas/_libs/groupby.c:27831:40: warning: self-comparison always evaluates to true [-Wtautological-compare]
            __pyx_t_24 = ((__pyx_v_val == __pyx_v_val) != 0);
                                       ^
pandas/_libs/groupby.c:28616:40: warning: self-comparison always evaluates to true [-Wtautological-compare]
            __pyx_t_24 = ((__pyx_v_val == __pyx_v_val) != 0);
                                       ^
3 warnings generated.
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/groupby.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -o build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/groupby.cpython-37m-darwin.so
building 'pandas._libs.hashing' extension
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c pandas/_libs/hashing.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/hashing.o -Wno-unused-function
In file included from pandas/_libs/hashing.c:567:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822:
/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
 ^
1 warning generated.
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/hashing.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -o build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/hashing.cpython-37m-darwin.so
building 'pandas._libs.hashtable' extension
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c pandas/_libs/hashtable.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/hashtable.o -Wno-unused-function
In file included from pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:568:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822:
/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
 ^
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:14483:38: warning: self-comparison always evaluates to false [-Wtautological-compare]
          __pyx_t_15 = ((__pyx_v_val != __pyx_v_val) != 0);
                                     ^
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:18312:38: warning: self-comparison always evaluates to false [-Wtautological-compare]
          __pyx_t_15 = ((__pyx_v_val != __pyx_v_val) != 0);
                                     ^
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20467:13: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
  __pyx_t_6 = get_c_string(__pyx_v_val); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_6 == ((char *)NULL))) __PYX_ERR(0, 1249, __pyx_L1_error)
            ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20696:13: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
  __pyx_t_8 = get_c_string(__pyx_t_1); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_8 == ((char *)NULL))) __PYX_ERR(0, 1263, __pyx_L1_error)
            ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:21062:16: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    __pyx_t_12 = get_c_string(__pyx_v_val); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_12 == ((char *)NULL))) __PYX_ERR(0, 1286, __pyx_L1_error)
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:21397:16: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    __pyx_t_11 = get_c_string(__pyx_v_val); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_11 == ((char *)NULL))) __PYX_ERR(0, 1316, __pyx_L1_error)
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:22033:18: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      __pyx_t_13 = get_c_string(__pyx_v_val); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_13 == ((char *)NULL))) __PYX_ERR(0, 1357, __pyx_L1_error)
                 ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:22056:18: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      __pyx_t_13 = get_c_string(__pyx_t_6); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_13 == ((char *)NULL))) __PYX_ERR(0, 1359, __pyx_L1_error)
                 ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:22428:17: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      __pyx_t_8 = get_c_string(__pyx_v_val); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_8 == ((char *)NULL))) __PYX_ERR(0, 1390, __pyx_L1_error)
                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:22451:17: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      __pyx_t_8 = get_c_string(__pyx_t_4); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_8 == ((char *)NULL))) __PYX_ERR(0, 1392, __pyx_L1_error)
                ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:22968:18: warning: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
      __pyx_t_14 = get_c_string(__pyx_v_val); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_14 == ((char *)NULL))) __PYX_ERR(0, 1431, __pyx_L1_error)
                 ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:27585:19: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') [-Wsign-compare]
  if (((__pyx_t_1 < __pyx_t_2) != 0)) {
        ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:29631:39: warning: self-comparison always evaluates to false [-Wtautological-compare]
            __pyx_t_17 = (__pyx_v_val != __pyx_v_val);
                                      ^
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:29411:19: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') [-Wsign-compare]
  if (((__pyx_t_1 < __pyx_t_2) != 0)) {
        ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:33087:39: warning: self-comparison always evaluates to false [-Wtautological-compare]
            __pyx_t_17 = (__pyx_v_val != __pyx_v_val);
                                      ^
pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:32867:19: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') [-Wsign-compare]
  if (((__pyx_t_1 < __pyx_t_2) != 0)) {
        ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
17 warnings generated.
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/hashtable.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -o build/lib.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/hashtable.cpython-37m-darwin.so
building 'pandas._libs.index' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/src
creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/src/datetime
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c pandas/_libs/index.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/index.o -Wno-unused-function
In file included from pandas/_libs/index.c:568:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822:
/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
 ^
1 warning generated.
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-x86_64-3.7/pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime.o -Wno-unused-function
In file included from pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c:22:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
In file included from /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822:
/Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
 ^
pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c:518:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'convert_datetimestruct_to_datetime' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    convert_datetimestruct_to_datetime(fr, d, &result);
    ^
pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c:518:5: note: did you mean 'pandas_datetimestruct_to_datetime'?
pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c:514:14: note: 'pandas_datetimestruct_to_datetime' declared here
npy_datetime pandas_datetimestruct_to_datetime(PANDAS_DATETIMEUNIT fr,
             ^
pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c:530:5: error: implicit declaration of function 'convert_timedelta_to_timedeltastruct' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    convert_timedelta_to_timedeltastruct(fr, val, result);
    ^
pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c:530:5: note: did you mean 'pandas_timedelta_to_timedeltastruct'?
pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime.c:527:6: note: 'pandas_timedelta_to_timedeltastruct' declared here
void pandas_timedelta_to_timedeltastruct(npy_timedelta val,
     ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/yq/7j7wbssx4_98c2g9y4_sqsvc0000gp/T/pip-install-o9kr4joa/pandas/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/yq/7j7wbssx4_98c2g9y4_sqsvc0000gp/T/pip-install-o9kr4joa/pandas/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/yq/7j7wbssx4_98c2g9y4_sqsvc0000gp/T/pip-record-g6msurvw/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/g/ajudication/repos/mcp-data-mapping-utils/env/include/site/python3.7/pandas Check the logs for full command output.
```

Looks like it's something with `clang`. However I'm not entirely sure.

Error: `error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1`

So far I've reinstalled xcode and xcode-select. I'm also running python 3.7.9 in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're installing pandas v0.23.4, which doesn't have a pre-built binary for macOS 11 (this might be the case for all pandas versions, now that I'm looking).

This means you have to build pandas from source, which requires having the right build dependencies installed. Those numpy deprecation warnings makes me think you need an older version of numpy (I think they specify a minimum version, but not a max version).

Two suggestions:

1. Can you try using either pandas v0.25.3 (the last stable version before the 1.x release) or 1.2.1 (the current stable? The v0.25 release removed a bunch of old C code that should help avoid some of these errors.
2. Before installing pandas, can you install an older version of numpy? 1.13.3 was the minimum required version at the time of the 0.25.3 release, something roughly from there up to a couple of major versions higher should work.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I tried using the versions you mentioned for pandas and numpy in the install however still did not work. 

Below is the full original list:

Comment: abbreviations==0.1.5
Flask==1.0.2
flask-cors==3.0.8
fuzzywuzzy[speedup]==0.17.0
gunicorn==19.9.0
json-logging==1.0.5
jsonschema==3.2.0
lxml==4.4.1
notebook==6.0.2
numpy==1.16.5
objectpath==0.6.1
openpyxl==3.0.1
pandas==0.23.4
pre-commit==1.20.0
progressbar2==3.47.0
pylint==2.3.1
pytest-cov==2.6.1
pytest==5.2.4
python-Levenshtein==0.12.0
python-dotenv[cli]==0.10.3
python-utils==2.3.0
recommonmark==0.5.0
requests==2.22.0
Sphinx==2.0.1
xlrd==1.2.0
XlsxWriter==1.2.6
requests-mock==1.8.0
flasgger==0.9.5

Comment: Any more suggestions? @mattficke